# When to use a template non-type argument VS. a constructor parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

What are the differences between a template non-type parameter and a constructor parameter used as a constant? When should each be preferred?

For example, see below MyArray, whose constructor initializes an internal vector using the template parameter N. Instead, MyArray2 takes N from a constructor parameter. Methods "fill" and "print" are identical in both classes, so the only difference is the template and the constructor.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int N>
class MyArray {
    private:
        std::vector<T> internal_array;
    public:
        MyArray() : internal_array{std::vector<T>(N)}{}
        void fill(int n) {
            for (auto& x : internal_array) {
                x = n;
            }
        }
        void print() {
            for (auto x : internal_array) {
                std::cout << x;
            }
        }
};

template<typename T>
class MyArray2 {
    private:
        std::vector<T> internal_array;
    public:
        MyArray2(int N) : internal_array{std::vector<T>(N)}{}
        void fill(int n) {
            for (auto& x : internal_array) {
                x = n;
            }
        }
        void print() {
            for (auto x : internal_array) {
                std::cout << x;
            }
        }
};

int main() {
    MyArray<int, 10> a;
    MyArray2<int> b(10);
    a.fill(1);
    a.print();
    b.fill(2);
    b.print();
}
```

Output:

```
11111111112222222222
```

Comment: Template non-type arguments must be compile-time constants. Constructor arguments could be run-time values.

Comment: `std::array<T, N>` versus `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template non-type parameters are generally more restrictive than function/constructor parameters, but they can also do some unique things when compile time constants are needed.

Commonly they will be mainly an optimization benefit and sometimes the code can be simpler, e.g. in your `MyArray` case, or a `std::array`.

```
template<typename T, int N>
class MyArray {
    private:
        T internal_array[N]; // No extra allocation here
    public:
        MyArray() {}
        void fill(int n) {
            for (auto& x : internal_array) { // The compiler can easily optimize loops like this, as the number of loops is known.
                x = n;
            }
        }
        void print() {
            for (auto x : internal_array) {
                std::cout << x;
            }
        }
};
```

Another is that it is possible to have things like the return type, arguments, or other functionality, be dependent on a non-type parameter, for example see `std::get<i>(my_tuple)` where `i` is known at compile time, the return type will be the type of that tuples element, if it was say `std::get(i, my_tuple)` then it couldn't have different return types.

```
std::tuple<std::string, int> t = { "example", 42 };
std::string str = std::get<0>(t);
int x = std::get<1>(t);
```

I have also seen "flags" specified this way where compile time constants are later needed, or to get the compiler to optimize the specific cases better.

```
my_function<CASE_INSENSITIVE | NO_UNICODE>(a, b, c);
```